# How to make columns stack with negative and positive y data in geom_col

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a graph in ggplot that will stack columns together, rather than overlapping them, which includes negative and positive values for each y axis variable.  Here is a sample of my dataset:

```
Depth<-c("75", "200", "350", "850", "1000")
BDay<-c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
BNight<-c(0, -1, -1, 0, 0)
CDay<-c(0, 0, 5, 23, 6)
CNight<-c(0, 0, -5, -36, -8)
df<-data.frame(Depth, BDay, BNight, CDay, CNight)
df
```

Here is a sample of my code for the graph:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=as.factor(Depth))) + 
  geom_col(aes(y = BDay,      fill="Species B"),    position=position_stack(reverse = TRUE)) +
  geom_col(aes(y = BNight,    fill="Species B"),    position=position_stack(reverse = TRUE)) +
  geom_col(aes(y = CDay,      fill="Species C"),    position=position_stack(reverse = TRUE)) + 
  geom_col(aes(y = CNight,    fill="Species C"),    position=position_stack(reverse = TRUE)) + 
  xlim("1000", "850", "350", "200", "75") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-40,40,5),limits = c(-40,40))+
  labs(title = "CTA Spring", x="Transect Depth (m)", y="Observations", fill="Species") +
  coord_flip() +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype="dashed") +
  theme_classic()+
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 15))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12))
```

And below is the output.  As you can see, the values overlap rather than stacking at 350 so that the data for BNight is not visible. I added in position=position_stack(reverse = TRUE), but this doesn't seem to fix the problem.  Is there another solution?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you use separate `geom_col` for each of your series as your data is in separate columns. Instead, to get a stacked barchart you have to reshape your data into long or tidy format using e.g. `tidyr::pivot_longer`. This way you can make your chart using just one `geom_col` and the bars get stacked:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

df_tidy <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(-Depth,
    # Split column names into species and time of day
    names_to = c("species", "time"),
    names_pattern = c("(.)(.*)"),
    values_to = "value"
  )

ggplot(df_tidy, aes(y = as.factor(Depth))) +
  geom_col(aes(x = value, fill = interaction(species, time)),
    position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE)
  ) +
  ylim("1000", "850", "350", "200", "75") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(-40, 40, 5), limits = c(-40, 40)) +
  labs(
    title = "CTA Spring", x = "Transect Depth (m)",
    y = "Observations", fill = "Species"
  ) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 15),
    axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12)
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Apologies for the really late reply to this answer (I posted and forgot about it, then encountered the exact same problem again), but it works!